# Number of Possible Pairs in Uneven-Sized Groups

Tags: combinatorics

I thought of this question the other day.

Suppose you have:

- 100 Gloves: G1, G2, G3 ... G99, G100
- 50 Hats: H1, H2, H3 ... H49, H50

How many "pairs of exactly one hat and exactly one glove" can be made?

At first I thought we can just group all these objects together and consider 150 objects - then we can find how many pairs can be made from these 150 objects:

150_C_2 = 150!/(2! * 148!) = 4950 pairs

But then I realized that this number (4950) would include "invalid pairs" of objects such as    (G87, G72).

- Is there some formula that can be used to find out the number of "valid" pairs that can be made?
- And is there some formula that can be used to find out the number of "valid" pairs that can be made between several groups. For example 100 Gloves, 50 Hats, 23 Shoes - how many combinations can be made involving 1 Glove, 1 Hat and 1 Shoe?

Thank you!

PS : I do not know the math required to calculate these combinations, but I wrote a small computer program to calculate these numbers (in R):

```
# How Many Combinations of 100 Gloves and 50 Hats? (My Guess: 5000)

num_1 = 1:100
gloves = "g"

data_1 = data.frame( gloves, num_1)
data_1$v1 = paste( data_1$gloves, data_1$num_1 ,sep = "")

num_2 = 1:50
hats = "h"

data_2 = data.frame( hats, num_2)
data_2$v2 = paste( data_2$hats, data_2$num_2, sep = "")

list.a <- as.list(c(data_1$v1))

list.b <- as.list(c(data_2$v2))

result.df <- expand.grid(list.a, list.b)

> dim(result.df)
[1] 5000    2

# How Many Combinations of 100 Gloves, 50 Hats and 23 Shoes? (My Guess: 115000)

 num_3 = 1:23
 pants = "p"
 
 data_3 = data.frame( pants, num_3)
 data_3$v3 = paste( data_3$pants, data_3$num_3, sep = "")
 
 list.c <- as.list(c(data_3$v3))
 
 result.df <- expand.grid(list.a, list.b, list.c)
 
 dim(result.df)
[1] 115000      3
```

Comment: For each hat, select a glove to be paired with it.  How many ways can you select the glove which is paired with the first hat? the second hat? Continue.

Comment: @  
N. F. Taussig : thank you for your suggestion - I am still thinking about how to solve this mathematically, but in the meantime, I wrote some computer code to list all the possibilities - can you please take a look at this? Thank you so much!

Comment: If you are still having trouble approaching the problem mathematically, try solving a smaller version of the problem.  How many pairings can you make if you have four distinct gloves and two distinct hats?  That will allow you list all the possibilities and may allow you to find a mathematical formula which solves the problem.  A tree diagram may help you obtain the formula.

Answer (score 1):

A pair consists of a hat and a glove. There are $50$ choices for the hat, and $100$ choices for the glove. Therefore, by the multiplication principle, the number of valid pairs is $50\times 100$.

Similarly, for the hat/glove/shoe situation you mentioned, there would be $50\times 100\times 23$ ways to choose one of each.

You can also solve the hat/glove problem via complementary counting. I will use $\binom nk$ instead of ${}_nC_k$. There are $\binom{150}2$ ways to choose a pair of two items, but you need to subtract away pairs of two gloves and pairs of two hats. There are $\binom{100}2$ ways to choose a pair of two gloves, and $\binom{50}2$ ways to choose a pair of two hats. Therefore, the number of remaining pairs is
$$
\binom{150}2-\binom{100}2-\binom{50}2
$$
You can check that this equals $50\times 100$.

Comment: @ Mike Earnest : Thank you! I guess my computer code is correct? Thanks!

Comment: I guess so, but I do not speak R, so I cannot confirm.

Comment: Thank you so much!